# The proper way to create a 2d android game

Tags: android, 2d

After getting help with starting android pong, I realized that I painted myself into a corner.

For reference on the code(Its long) and advice, here is a link to the last thread [Updating player score in an android game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652347/updating-player-score-in-an-android-game)

Basically the frame rate is halved when i touch the screen.  I think it is due to updating everything or drawing on the canvas.  This also lends itself to bad communication between the pieces of the application(the view, frame, and oncreate).  Is there a recommended way to create an android 2d game?  This is based off the lunar landing game and it seemed fine but when i tried to recreate it , it seemed much worse.  I could not find a lot of resource on a best practice for drawing and so far this seems a bit discouraging.

So in short

How would you modify the code posted in the link to improve performance?  Or did I paint myself into a poorly made corner, and it is time to start a new? If so , how?

Thanks

Comment: If you are serious about this check: http://www.andengine.org/ the professional way seems to use openGl and perhaps box2D for physical simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need invalidate() in onTouch because you are already running a frame animation by the additional thread.

Try to define all the fixed values/variables in the constructor of the SurfaceView or in onSizeChanged() where you know the size of the canvas and bitmaps loaded, so not to make any unneccesary variable creation, requests or calcualtions in onDraw, onTouch or other methods to handle game logic, otherwise it will slow down.